# invalid javascript parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

so i have this button, which is added dynamically in java script, but the thing is a want to send the files name as a parameter to the function, i already have the name in a var saved as file, the name is generally something like p164.epub.    but for some reason it wont accept the parameter.   if for instance i add a number instead of file, it accepts it and it works as it should

```
$('#result2').append("<button class ='removeBtn' onclick ='removeEbook("+file+")'>Remove</button>");
```

my function

```
function removeEbook(n)
{
  alert("yay");
}
```

any thoughts?

Comment: maybe a typo but double quotes are needed around `"<button ... </button>"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have to send file name in single quotes and use escape character for double qoutes like belwo

```
$('#result2').append("<button class =\"removeBtn\" onclick =\"removeEbook('"+file+"')\">Remove</button>");
```

Comment: dude!!!! love you man, you dont understand how long iv been struggling with this!!!  you sir are a hero

Comment: no, you _don't_ have to do this, so long as you use single quotes for your JS strings, and double quotes for HTML attributes.  If you _must_ use inline event handlers (and you really shouldn't) then ogc-nick's answer is better than this, because it only escapes the innermost string, not every quote mark

Comment: @Alnitak, this is one of the solution. there can be different solutions for single problem. I have just corrected the used code to make it working.

Comment: wait, this turns it into a object at the function and it seems to be undefined,   how would i go around accessing the element?

Comment: @user1752451 you can access the element _by using a proper event handler_!

Comment: yes, you accepted the wrong answer.  If you aren't going to fix your code, you should have at least used ogc-nick's answer instead of this one.

Answer (score 3):

You have jQuery - don't use inline event handlers:

```
var file = '...';

$('<button class="removeBtn">').text('Remove').on('click', function() {
    // NB: "this" refers to the clicked button
    removeEbook(file);
}).appendTo('$#result2');
```

If you insist on using inline event handlers (and you really shouldn't), best practise is to use single quotes for your JS strings, and double quotes for the attributes within your HTML, e.g.:

```
$('#result2').append('<button class="removeBtn" onclick="removeEbook(\''+file+'\')">Remove</button>');
```

Note that as written this will bind the handler to whatever value `file` has at the time the handler is registered (because the code above turns it into a string constant) instead of whatever value it has when it's triggered.

Note that if `file` happens to contain *any* quote characters (which is perfectly legal on some systems) you will end up with an illegal string constant.

The above are just two of the many reasons why inline event handlers shouldn't be used.  They're error prone (as you've found).

Comment: gah - just had to correct an error in the escaped string version that got through because _inline handlers and escaped strings are a right pain and shouldn't be used_!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add escaped quotes around the string parameter.

```
$('#result2').append("<button class ='removeBtn' onclick ='removeEbook(\'"+file+"\')'>Remove</button>");
```

Comment: +1 for escaping the right characters, instead of using the same quote marks everywhere and then having to quote too many!